# Reading Json Response from API with AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have JSON data. I need to read this data by sending from postman and I need to parse the data and I need to insert the data into the database. I am trying to do it in Python and, it should be done with the AWS lambda function. How can I do this?
**The code I am using is**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print(event)
    # http_method = event['httpMethod']
   
    # if http_method == 'GET':
    #   print("request post")
    #   id = event['queryStringParameters']['id']
    #   name = event['queryStringParameters']['name']
    #   points = event['queryStringParameters']['points']
    # elif http_method == 'POST':
    bodyk = json.dumps(event["body"])
    print(type(body))
    body2 = json.loads(body)
    body3 = body2
    conn.commit()
    return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps("hello")
    }
```

When I am trying with code when I ikove lambda with postman it is saying that "key-error": body
........................................................................................................

> { belo is the json format
> "globalsettings" : [{     "id" : 1,   "name" : "veteran",     "points" : 40 }, {  "id" : 2,   "name" : "disabled_veteran",    "points" : 20 }, {
> "id" : 3,   "name" : "tenure",  "points" : 40 }, {  "id" : 4,   "name"
> : "performance",  "points" : 30 }, {  "id" : 5,   "name" : "suspended",
> "points" : 5 }] }

Comment: Can you please add the input payload

Comment: {
    "globalsettings" : [{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "veteran",
 "points" : 40
},
{
 "id" : 2,
 "name" : "disabled_veteran",
 "points" : 20
},
{
 "id" : 3,
 "name" : "tenure",
 "points" : 40
},
{
 "id" : 4,
 "name" : "performance",
 "points" : 30
},
{
 "id" : 5,
 "name" : "suspended",
 "points" : 5
}]
}

Comment: Your event object will be the same input you're sending. I don't see "body" field in your input. Usually "body" will be coming with SQS lambda integrations.

Comment: can you format my input file with body my frontend engineer told me that this will be the json I am going to receive , So if you can give me an update about that  json format , I will inform my frontend engineer, which will The lambda can read and it can insert into db from frontend we are using React Js for frontend

Comment: Just put a print of our event object and write it accordingly. If your frontend dev embed the json into body then it'll be fine